# NFC ( Near Field Communication ) app development queries for Android

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest, nfc

Can we make application that support `NFC (near field communication)` for android devices without using *Google nexus* or *Samsung Galaxy* `NFC` supported phone. Actually i want to know the specification material to develop  `NFC application` for android .

What is the **initial requirements** for developing `NFC( Near Field Communication ) App` for Android ?

If yes ,then suggest me some good metters or links for development. i am in confusion that how i will get tags for testing and **how i can write data in tags.** There r many a makemind confusing questions .

Please do something needful Help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer this [book](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449389697/ch18_id300804.html) to get a general idea about NFC programming.

Then you can refer this [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/index.html) to learn how to read/write to a NFC tag.

CardEmulation can be referenced [here](http://www.open-nfc.org/opennfc_library/reference/org/opennfc/cardemulation/CardEmulation.html).

All the best!

Comment: Thanks TheCottonSilk for your help. I think u have provided me the conclusion of Internet material for NFC Android Development.Expect it there are no more food help for NFC development.I am beginner in android platform. Have u build any android NFC application. Please help me in future if u know better in NFC.

Comment: @Rana.S I did not get any chance to develop a NFC based application. I studied it on my own interest and I'm planning to develop one soon. However you can always ask any NFC related question to the SO community, we all are there to help! Since you are a beginner in Android, you try out Google tutorials first to get familiar with basic APIs, then you can move on to NFC: First read and understand very clearly what is it, where it can be used, then you can try out the NFC related examples. Later you can build on this knowledge set and plan for a more complex application.